# Python/Selenium - Clicking all elements on a particular div

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

So, I have this code that search for some data and tries to download the files that the search has returned.

It can do the search pretty well, but i'm facing some issues when trying to download it. The download link is through this <a WGet script for... </a that is displayed on the picture I've uploaded.

[picture with <a element that I need to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zoiW.png)

The problem is that, depending on the search, the number of available links differs. In this particular case, I have one, but sometimes there are two, three, even eight.

I need a way to click them all dynamically, no matter how many of them I have.
I've tried two ways, but both has failed:

```
                wgetScripts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'WGET Script for')]").click()
```

and

```
                wgetScripts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'WGET Script for')]")
            for button in wgetScripts:
                button.click()
```

I cannot find the elements by id, class, or something else, cause the element is just a plain <a with only a href. No id, no class, nothing at all.

HTML for the element is:

```
<a href="javascript:wgetScript(&quot;esgf-node.llnl.gov&quot;)">WGET Script for esgf-node.llnl.gov</a>
```

Comment: the 2nd option should have worked. can you post the error mesasge you are getting?

Comment: @FábioPiovani Where are you stuck?

Comment: sure! 
the error message I get when running second option is:

  File "/home/fabiopiovani/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: @FábioPiovani Can you try adding some additional wait before clicking on the button element? an explicit wait will work, i think.

Comment: @Sureshmani I've tried with 5, 10 and 15 seconds, none of them worked

Comment: still getting the same error?

Comment: @Sureshmani yes, same error

Comment: does anyone have any idea to help me?